# Only DAT company found

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, ax, dynamics-ax-2012

I have installed Dynamic AX 2012 and I have checked AOS.

After steps of configuration Dynamics AX I restart it and when I want to go to the legal company CEU or other I cannot!

I have just a windows called DAT.

Only DAT found in dynamics ax 2012!

How can I get access to CEU and find AOT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you, you have access to the DAT company only and with no rights?

This will give no or few menu items.

The most likely course: you changed roles or security groups of your user. Try with another user with Admin power if possible.

**Update:**
If it fails you will have to restore a backup copy of your database. First make an SQL log backup, then do a point-in-time restore to a time before your configuration setup.

Comment: i found my user as an admnistrator but i could not acces again  could you show me how we can fix the problem by sending a screenshot

Comment: I don't think a sceenshot will help you. Try logging in as another user.

Comment: I 'am connect to another user i acces to dynamic ax but when i acces with developpempent mode i have not acces to the mode developper  .

Comment: I 'am connected with another user i access to dynamic ax but when i acces with developempent mode but an error is displayed " Insufficient rights to open development tools".

Comment: i connect with other admin user but Dynamics AX can not run because i don't have sufficient right ! and with my account i can open dynamics ax and when i specify -development in property of dynamics ax, a message error say i don't have permission to open development mode...

Comment: You will then have to restore a backup copy of your database. First make an SQL log backup, then do a point-in-time restore to a time before your configuration setup.

Comment: i am a sysadmin in the sqlserverer there are a way how to add user as a systemAdmnistaor on dynamic ax

Comment: There probably is, but none I know. I would go for the restore as it is way faster.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps - I had this bug also after initialization of a new client, I have no Modules appearing and I get the infolog regarding No Permissions. I had to uninstall everything, re-install the Database (this sets up a new SQL Server Database), Application Files, AOS and the Client / Debugger. During setup ensure you use correct logins (I would assume this is where the permissions error start from), but it might also be from the imported data (not too sure on this one though). After this I launched the AOS (it takes some time first time round), and then during initialization of the client you set up the client and carry out the import of your data. Another thing, ensure you have updated any service packs, and brought in the latest build into the application folder.